# How does Spark parallelize the processing of a 1TB file?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

**Imaginary problem**

- A gigantic CSV log file, let's say 1 TB in size, the file is located on a USB drive
- The log contains activities logs of users around the world, let's assume that the line contains 50 columns, among those there is Country.
- We want a line count per country, descending order.
- Let's assume the Spark cluster has enough nodes with RAM to process the entire 1TB in memory (20 nodes, 4 cores CPU, each node has 64GB RAM)

**My Poorman's conceptual solution**
Using [SparkSQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) & [Databricks spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

```
$ ./spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

```scala
val dfBigLog = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("/media/username/myUSBdrive/bogusBigLog1TB.log")

dfBigLog.select("Country")
  .groupBy("Country")
  .agg(count($"Country") as "CountryCount")
  .orderBy($"CountryCount".desc).show
```

**Question 1: How does Spark parallelize the processing?**

I suppose the majority of the execution time (99% ?) of the above solution is to read the 1TB file from the USB drive into the Spark cluster. Reading the file from the USB drive is not parallelizable. But after reading the entire file, what does Spark do under the hood to parallelize the processing?

- How many nodes used for creating the DataFrame? (maybe only one?)
- How many nodes used for `groupBy` & `count`? Let's assume there are 100+ countries (but Spark doesn't know that yet). How would Spark partition to distribute the 100+ country values on 20 nodes?

**Question 2: How to make the Spark application the fastest possible?**
I suppose the area of improvement would be to parallelize the reading of the 1TB file.

- Convert the CSV File into a Parquet file format + using Snappy compression. Let's assume this can be done in advance.
- Copy the Parquet file on HDFS. Let's assume the Spark cluster is within the same Hadoop cluster and the datanodes are independant from the 20 nodes Spark cluster.
- Change the Spark application to read from HDFS. I suppose Spark would now use several nodes to read the file as Parquet is splittable.
- Let's assume the Parquet file compressed by Snappy is 10x smaller, size = 100GB, HDFS block = 128 MB in size. Total 782 HDFS blocks.

But then how does Spark manage to use all the 20 nodes for both creating the DataFrame and the processing (`groupBy` and `count`)? Does Spark use all the nodes each time?

Answer (score 7):

> Question 1: How does Spark parallelize the processing (of reading a
>   file from a USB drive)?

**This scenario is not possible.**

Spark relies on a hadoop compliant filesystem to read a file. When you mount the USB drive, you can only access it from the local host. Attempting to execute

```
.load("/media/username/myUSBdrive/bogusBigLog1TB.log")
```

will fail in cluster configuration, as executors in the cluster will not have access to that local path.

It would be possible to read the file with Spark in local mode (`master=local[*]`) in which case you only will have 1 host and hence the rest of the questions would not apply.

> Question 2: How to make the Spark application the fastest possible?

**Divide and conquer.**
The strategy outlined in the question is good. Using Parquet will allow Spark to do a projection on the data and only `.select("Country")` column, further reducing the amount of data required to be ingested and hence speeding things up.

The cornerstone to parallelism in Spark are partitions. Again, as we are reading from a file, Spark relies on the Hadoop filesystem. When reading from HDFS, the partitioning will be dictated by the splits of the file on HDFS. Those splits will be evenly distributed among the executors. That's how Spark will initially distribute the work across all available executors for the job.

I'm not deeply familiar with the Catalist optimizations, but I think I could assume that `.groupBy("Country").agg(count($"Country")` will become something similar to: `rdd.map(country => (country,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)` 
The map operation will not affect partitioning, so can be applied on site.
The reduceByKey will be applied first locally on each partition and partial results will be combined on the driver.  So most counting happens distributed in the cluster, and adding it up will be centralized.

Comment: Thanks to Parquet, Spark will scan only the HDFS blocks related to the Country column. Let's assume this involves 200 blocks of the 782 total. As there are 20 nodes in the Spark cluster, lets assume each node has 4 cores CPU. Is it correct to say that Spark will read the 200 blocks and  distribute the blocks among 80 workers (partitioned by 200 modulo 8)? Then where do Spark get compute resources for the reducers? I suppose Spark will reserve some cores for driver, some for mappers some for reducers. How does Spark know how many cores to allocate each BEFORE reading the data?

Comment: @Polymerase  In Spark, there's no resource allocation per operation type, so in theory all 80 executing cores will be working on this job. The unit of computation is a 'task' which is a partition + stage. A stage is a sequence of operations that can be pipelined together. Operations on RDD form a Direct Acyclic graph (DAG) that's analysed by the scheduler, which will dispatch the tasks for the different stages to the  cluster.

Comment: @Polymerase check out this presentation I gave a while ago: https://youtu.be/V938kCyTwPg?t=500

Comment: Your explanation is shown in the video (14:00 to 17:00). Thx, there is a lots of goodies in this video. At 16:30, where you showed the results of map side reduce of Stage1 (blue outline rectangle) -> Shuffle -> Stage2 (green rectangle) which aggregates the final count per the Country key. Where does Spark get the compute resource (executor?) for Stage2? Because all available 80 executors were already used in Stage1. They have to be alive so Spark can shuffle their results to other executors of Stage2. S2 needs N executors to receive these results. Where does S2 get these N executors?

Comment: Sorry off topic. How to you put the at sign and the name of the user? I began my comment by "@ maasg" (no quote no space) but when I posted the comment, the "@ massg" is removed.

Comment: "Spark relies on a hadoop compliant filesystem to read a file. When you mount the USB drive, you can only access it from the local host." Not completely true. Use `spark-submit --files /path/to/usb/file.csv` and then in your code use `SparkFiles.get("file.csv")`. Use the returned string path in all places you'll use the original path. Spark will read from the usb and distribute the file to all the worker nodes.

Answer (score 3):

> Reading the file from the USB drive is not parallelizable.

USB drive or any other data source the same rules apply. Either source is accessible from the driver and all worker machines and data is accessed in parallel (up to the source limits) or data is not accessed at all you get an exception.

> How many nodes used for creating the DataFrame? (maybe only one?)

Assuming that files is accessible from all machines it depends on a configuration. For starters you should take a look at the split size.

> How many nodes used for the GroupBy & Count?

Once again it depends on a configuration.

Comment: Hi, which split size were you referring to? The 1TB source file is in the USB drive, how to evaluate the split size? Depends on a configuration: can you please suggest the configuration items? I will look into it further. Thanks.